# ExpressJS + Webpack + react-router v4

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, server-side

I am trying to set up my own boilerplate for creating react app just to know what is going on behind the scenes.

I am stuck at server rendering using Webpack/ Express/ react-router v4. Just don't know how to solve it.

My `express.js` file looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
const StaticRouter = require('react-router').StaticRouter;
const App = require('./src/app');

const app = express();

// Views
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'templates'))

// Middlewares
app.use(morgan(':method :url :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms'));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Paths
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const context = {}
  const html = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
    <StaticRouter
      location={req.url}
      context={context}
    >
      <App/>
    </StaticRouter>
  )
  res.render('index', {reactOutput: html});
  // Then in my index.ejs put a <%- reactOutput %> 
});

const port = 8000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port', port);
})
```

What are the next steps to make it work? What I was thinking:
1. Define new entry in `webpack.config.js` for `express.js`
2. Fire up the `express.bundle.js` created by Webpack using `node express.bundle.js`

But as soon as I try to run `webpack -p` I get errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/request.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'net' in '/Users/NYC/Desktop/JavaScript/Boilerplate/client/node_modules/express/lib'

ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/NYC/Desktop/JavaScript/Boilerplate/client/node_modules/express/lib'

ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/NYC/Desktop/JavaScript/Boilerplate/client/node_modules/send'

ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/NYC/Desktop/JavaScript/Boilerplate/client/node_modules/etag'

ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/NYC/Desktop/JavaScript/Boilerplate/client/node_modules/destroy'

ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/NYC/Desktop/JavaScript/Boilerplate/client/node_modules/mime'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `target: 'node'` to your webpack configuration file.

For more information, you can read at https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/